# In Next.js, under what circumstances, will the 'getInitialProps' in file _error.js have 'req' defined yet 'err' undefined?

Tags: next.js

I am confused at the situation leading to _error page.

From my understanding, there are several scenario leading to _error page.

1. when there is a client-side error, which leads to _error page with '**err**' defined and '**req**' undefined
2. when entering a page not in router, which leads to _error page with '**err**' undefined and '**req**' undefined
3. when there is a server-side error, which leads to _error page with '**err**' defined and '**req**' defined

My question is :
under what circumstance(s), the _error page will have '**err**' undefined yet '**req**' defined?

```
Error.getInitialProps = async ({
  pathname,
  asPath,
  query,
  req,
  res,
  err,
}: any) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404
  if (req) {
    if (req.metrics && req.logger) {
      req.metrics.emitCounter('error_page', 1)
      req.logger.error(
        `[error page] status code = ${statusCode}  error message = ${err?.message} error stack = ${err?.stack}`
      )
    }
  }
```

As code above, I get following log:

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `req` is not defined when accessing a page not in Next.js router? I can see the `req` object in that scenario.

Comment: whether `req` is defined is determined by whether the error occurs in client-side or server-side, isn't it ? So when accessing a page not in Next.js router, I guess the 404 page is not relative to server-side code? @juliomalves

Comment: When typing a path that doesn't exist in the address bar the server will be handling that error, and `req` will be defined.

Comment: You are right. Thanks I eventually understand how it works.